# String.indexOf gives a value one less than expected

Tags: java, string, indexof

I do not understand the behaviour of the String.index Of method.

```
String peter = "Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled pepper";
  System.out.println("The number of p in the sentence is, " + peter.indexOf('p'));
```

Why is the output of p 8 and not 9? There are 9 P's in the sentence.

Comment: What do you think `indexOf` does? Why do you think so? What makes you think it's a count?

Comment: You tried checking the [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes are zero-based:

```
        ↓
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled pepper
          111111111122222222223333333333444
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
        ↑
```

The *first* `p` is at index `8`.

From the javadoc of [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29):

> Returns the **index** of the **first occurrence** of the character in the character sequence represented by this object, or `-1` if the character does not occur.